# How to know the No. of java files in my workspace in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, count

I have a java project with a lot java files. So, I want to know the number of `.java` files in my project in Eclipse. How to know that?

Comment: in your _workspace_ or in your _project_ ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to show the resources. Then enter `*.java` and mark all items of the list (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>). The list will give you a summary how many resources it has found.

Comment: I would like to know the number. I am not able count the whole list.

Comment: I added the way how to get the number to the answer.

Comment: @martijn. I tried but it told me to wait for 8 minutes, So had some work I forgot to accept.

Answer (score 4):

Other way is to search for something in '**File search**'(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) with '**File name patterns**' as '*.java'.
As soon as you hit Search button, it will show you the number of java files on the bottom.

***For eg:*** Scanning file xx of xxxx. Where `xxxx` will be the number of java files in your project. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [JavaNCSS](http://javancss.codehaus.org/) - it provides many relevant code metrics.